# Dynamically change redux-form based on field values

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have a form composed of three fields. If field #1 has value equal to `true`, field #3 has to be removed from the form, if field #1 has value equal to `false`, field #3 needs to be put back on the form.

I'm not finding a easy, clean way of doing this.

One of the examples on the redux-form site explains how to dynamically build a form based on the state of the form's container. The container passes the field array to the form component as a `prop`, and the input fields that control the field array are within the container. I cannot really use that approach, since field #1 has to be within the form.

I've tried to simply hide field #3 using CSS, however the validation rules are not aware of which fields are hidden or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to modify the structure of the form, and just want to hide the field, maybe this will work for you:

```
render() {
  const {yourField1, yourField3} = this.props;
  <div>
    <Input type="text" {...yourField1} />
    { !yourField1.value && 
        <Input type="text" {...yourField3} />}
  </div>
```

Comment: That will work, but I woul still need to test for the value of the yourField1 in my validation function, otherwise yourField3 will still be validated.

Comment: Take a look at the example for SynchronousValidationForm in the documentation http://redux-form.com/5.2.5/#/examples/synchronous-validation?_k=cpiwib you will validate yourField3 only if yourField1 is false

Comment: yes, that's what I meant by saying "I would need to test for the value of the yourField1 in my validation function". I thought there would be a way to completely remove the field from my form. Anyways, I guess I'll leave the question open for a bit longer in case someone comes up with a better solution. Thanks @parecementeria !